# PHP/JavaScript OnMouseOver link not working

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, mouseover

I have been working on a script to change an image to a link when it's being hovered.

Yet, the link cannot be clicked. The cursor does change to a pointer and I can see the link in the bottom left of my browser, but nothing happens when I click it.

It does seem to work in Firefox, not in any other browser.
Right mouseclick -> Open in new tab, does work however.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var guesta='<a href="<?php $menu = JSite::getMenu();$alias = $menu->getItem(115)->alias;echo $alias; ?>"><?php $menu = JSite::getMenu();$title = $menu->getItem(115)->title;echo $title; ?></a>';


function guest1(){
document.getElementById('guest1').innerHTML=guesta;
document.getElementById('guest1').style.background ='#01afae';
}
function guest1empty(){
document.getElementById('guest1').innerHTML='<img src="image.png" />';
document.getElementById('guest1').style.background ='#fdfdfd';
}
//-->
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.guest {
    width:70px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    color: #fdfdfd;
    text-align: center;
}
.guest a:link, .guest a:visited {
    color: #fdfdfd;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="guest1" class="guest" onMouseOver="guest1()" onMouseOut="guest1empty()"><img src="image.png" /></div>
```

The PHP code inside the link is to retrieve an menu-item alias and title from Joomla.

Thank you very, very much for any help!

Best regards,

Jerome

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest actually creating the elements using document.createElement("IMG") and document.createElement("A"). That's the surest way to know that the element will be created properly.
This does not, however, seem like a very practical approach to me. Why would you not just have the image be a link to begin with? Why have the hover state change it back and forth?
As one last though, have you tried echoing out the contents of the Joomla return value to be sure you're even getting content back? Frameworks can be *extremely* finnickey and so it can be difficult to figure out where exactly you're getting an error.
Let us know!

Comment: Ahh, also, you have calls to functions inside of the quotes. As far as I was aware, that won't work. Assign the $menu->getItem(115).... to a variable BEFORE inserting it into a string.
Also, when posting code, please format it a bit better, it's hard to read when you put a bunch of inline variable declarations (inside a string, no less).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I just started with Javascript and these are the first few thing I learned. I will Google around to learn about createElement.

The image would be a photo of a lecturer, when hovering the image should disappear and the name of the lecturer must be shown on the greenish background. This link, made by the PHP script and Joomla, should be able to display a detailed page of the lecturer.
Please keep in mind, eventually I will have ~30 lecturers in a grid, with menu-IDs from 115 and higher, each with their own photo and detail page.

Comment: Read into unobtrusive javascript as well. Adding events to an element is not as good of practice as it once was. You should be able to give each image an ID and be able to reference it in some other way. You should never have to turn something into a link on mouse over.

Comment: Could you give me a start?

When I change the beginning to;
    `<?php
     $menu = JSite::getMenu();
     $title = $menu->getItem(115)->title;
    ?>
    <?php
     $menu = JSite::getMenu();
     $alias = $menu->getItem(115)->alias;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    var guesta='<a href="<?php echo $alias ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a>';`

The entire PHP section doesn't work anymore..

Comment: Firstly, you don't have to open and close your PHP tags between statements. Is this jssite::getmenu function called multiple times because it automatically returns a different value? You have it twice
Because I don't know your framework, I can't say anything with certainty, but I would try to restructure how you're doing your HTML markup so you don't have to try these tricks with the PHP and JS.
Why not just put an image and insert the link as the page loads? Is the JS necessary? With css styling the link wouldn't even be visible anyways- I cant see why you're doing it the way you're doing it.

Comment: I think the JS is necessary. The image needs to be shown when the page loads and when the user hovers over this image, the image turns into a green field with the output of the PHP-script. I can't seem to get it right...